# Delete and Update statements in Sqlite not working

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using SqlitePCL on a windows phone 8.1 application, 
I have the queries select and insert working but for some reason the delete and update are not working

Here are my codes:

Select Statement:

```
public static itemPassword[] AllGetItemPassword()
        {
            var db = App.conn;
            int numbofPass = 0;
            itemPassword[] itmpass = null;
            try
            {
                using (var statement = db.Prepare("SELECT nameWeb, username, password, link FROM Passwords"))
                {
                    while (statement.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
                    {
                        numbofPass++;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
```

Insert Statement:

```
    public void insertToDB(String usernameWeb, String userusername, String userpassword, String userlink)
    {
        var db = App.conn;

        try
        {
            using (var pass = db.Prepare("INSERT INTO Passwords (nameWeb, username, password, link) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"))
            {
                pass.Bind(1, usernameWeb);
                pass.Bind(2, "Username: " + userusername);
                pass.Bind(3, "Password: " + userpassword);
                pass.Bind(4, "Link: " + userlink);
                pass.Step();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
```

And now the not working codes:

Delete statement:

```
 public static void DeleteRecord12(string webname, string username , string password, string link)
        {
            var db = App.conn;
            try
            {
                using (var pass = db.Prepare("DELETE FROM Passwords WHERE webname = ? AND username = ? AND password = ? AND link = ?"))
                {
                    pass.Bind(1, webname);
                    pass.Bind(2, username);
                    pass.Bind(3, password);
                    pass.Bind(4, link);
                    pass.Step();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.GetType();
            }
        }
```

Update statement:

```
public void UpdateRecord(string webname, string username, string password, string link,string Newwebname, string Newusername, string Newpassword, string Newlink)
        {
            var db = App.conn;
            try
            {
                using (var pass = db.Prepare("UPDATE Passwords SET webname = ?, username = ?, password = ?, link = ? WHERE webname = ? AND username = ? AND password = ? AND link = ?"))
                {
                    pass.Bind(1, Newwebname);
                    pass.Bind(2, Newusername);
                    pass.Bind(3, Newpassword);
                    pass.Bind(4, Newlink);
                    pass.Bind(5, webname);
                    pass.Bind(6, username);
                    pass.Bind(7, password);
                    pass.Bind(8, link);
                    pass.Step();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.GetType();
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE:** 
It seems that sqlite Pcl on windows phone doesn't support the command "update" and when Selecting or deleting the WHERE command only supports "WHERE id=?" and not anything else like "WHERE name=belal".

Comment: Are any parameters passed to your `DELETE` statement, or any of parameters 5 to 8 passed to your `UPDATE` statement, null?

Comment: no i checked. any thoughts?

Comment: Your first mistake is `catch {}`. Never do that; it discards the error then continues as if nothing went wrong. But something did go wrong, and you threw away the error message. You need to see exceptions to diagnose problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting literal texts in front of the username and other variables in the insert statement. Because of this the record is never found when updating or deleting it. Remove the labels in front of the variables in the binds of the insert statement to get it to work:

```
public void insertToDB(String usernameWeb, String userusername, String userpassword, String userlink)
{
    var db = App.conn;

    try
    {
        using (var pass = db.Prepare("INSERT INTO Passwords (nameWeb, username, password, link) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"))
        {
            pass.Bind(1, usernameWeb);
            pass.Bind(2, userusername);
            pass.Bind(3, userpassword);
            pass.Bind(4, userlink);
            pass.Step();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
```

Comment: my problem is not with insert, it is with delete and update. Bu thanks for the answer

Comment: I got that, but these statements are not working because you're putting label text in some fields. The update and delete statements cannot find the record to update. For instance: you store a username as "Username: Rob", and then have your update statement update all records where username = 'Rob'. It will never update any records.

Comment: thank you for your help Rob, but it seems that sqlite Pcl on windows phone doesn't support the command "update" and when Selecting or deleting the WHERE command only supports "WHERE id=?" and not anything else like "WHERE name=belal".